# Can't programmatically change color set in storyboard as color from xcassets catalog

Tags: swift, xcode, colors, uicolor, xcasset

When I set color of some property in Storyboard (for example `textColor` of my `UILabel`) as color created as New Color Set in xcassets catalog

[image]

then I can't programmatically change this color on the first attempt:

```
label.textColor = UIColor(named: "HighlightedGreen")
```

... note that I'm calling it from data source method `cellForItemAt`.

**Hack:**
I can solve it by setting this color in Storyboard for any other color picked from color picker but I want to know why is this happening.

So, why is this happening?

Comment: It is important to know where are you trying this line `label.textColor = UIColor(named: "HighlightedGreen")`. `awakeFromXib`? `viewDidLoad`? somewhere else?

Comment: @Kamran in `UITableView` data source method `cellForItemAt`. So it's actually `cell.label.textColor = UIColor(named: "HighlightedGreen")`

Comment: Great to know. The solution will be to put this line inside `willDisplayCell` or `layoutSubviews` inside the cell class.

Comment: The reason it is not affected for the first time is because it's not yet loaded from the `storyboard`. For any `UIView`, `layoutSubviews` is the recommended method to update the subViews.

Comment: @Kamran yes, this explanation make sense for me and it works. Can you write it as answer (I would accept it)?

Comment: Turns out this is actually a Xcode bug. I've filed it as rdar://51208444 as it applies to even something as simple as setting the backgroundColor in viewDidLoad. `layoutSubviews` / `viewDidLayoutSubviews` still work as a workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a `UIView` `subClass` like `UITableViewCell` is loaded from the `Storyboard/Xib`, it applies the attributes specified in `Attribute Inspector` to all the `subViews`. We have the following callback methods to know when a view is loaded from the `Storyboard/Xib`,

```
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()        
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
```

These methods could be good candidates to add/remove a subView but they are not supposed to update the subView's `size` or some of `attribute inspector` related properties. The recommended method to update subViews is when the super view finishes loading and applying all the `attribute inspector` properties and calls `layoutSubviews`. So then you should apply any cosmetic change to a subView. e.g,

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    label.textColor = UIColor(named: "HighlightedGreen")
}
```

For a `UITableViewCell`, any object implementing `UITableViewDataSource` also guarantees a `delegate` method to apply any cosmetic change before the cell is being displayed as below, So this is also another good candidate to change the color.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    (cell as! MyListTableViewCell).label.textColor = UIColor(named: "HighlightedGreen")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very nice explanation.

Comment: `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` is not called at runtime. Did you mean `prepareForReuse()`?

Answer (score 5):

The real answer is that this is closer to a bug. In iOS 13 there is no problem overriding a color asset set in IB with any other color programmatically.

I grabbed some logs from an iOS 12 debug session where I attempted what the OP is doing:

> ***Cell 1***
>
> > **At awakeFromNib**: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.235 0.235 0.263 0.6
> > **Setting background color to**: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.235 0.235 0.263 0.6
> > **At layoutSubviews**: kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0.235 0.235 0.263 0.6
>
> ***Cell 2***
>
> > **At awakeFromNib**: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.235 0.235 0.263 0.6
> > **Setting background color to**: kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0.490196 0.760784 0.262745 1
> > **At layoutSubviews**: kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0.235 0.235 0.263 0.6

In iOS 13, the logs (and the results) are different:

> ***Cell 1***
>
> > **At awakeFromNib**: UIDynamicCatalogColor: 0x600003e83600; name = My Background Color
> > **Setting background color to**: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.235 0.235 0.263 0.6
> > **At layoutSubviews**: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.235 0.235 0.263 0.6
>
> ***Cell 2***
>
> > **At awakeFromNib**: UIDynamicCatalogColor: 0x600003e99290; name = My Background Color
> > **Setting background color to**: UIDynamicCatalogColor: 0x600003e99020; name = Button Green
> > **At layoutSubviews**: UIDynamicCatalogColor: 0x600003e99350; name = Button Green

It seems that there is a timing issue with when iOS 12 is translating the named color to the color space that it uses, occurring during `layoutSubviews()` so attempting to override the color before then is futile. However, iOS 13 seems to use UIDynamicCatalogColor natively without the translation, so there is no timing issue.

Color Assets seem to be a bit of an afterthought for Xcode overall. Good luck renaming them after they've been used throughout your app, using them with #colorLiteral, or changing them for different trait collections. Unfortunately the best solution for now seems to be to not use them in IB at all.