# Using colors from assets catalog in xib override colors set during UITableViewCell initialization

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, xib, asset-catalog

in our project we are switching to using colors from asset catalog. We are facing some weird problem when using new colors in XIBs.

Simple setup, table view, with cells populated from XIB:

```
tableView.register(R.nib.notificationTextListViewCell(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "id")
```

data source:

```
extension AddTraineeViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id", for: indexPath)
        let notificationCell = cell as? NotificationTextListViewCell
        notificationCell?.label?.text = "AAAAAAA"
        notificationCell?.label?.textColor = .blue
        return cell
    }
}
```

As you can see, I change textColor of the label to blue during configuration in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

If the color the text in xib is set to one of predefined ones (from "iPhoneSDK" section) everything works fine. Color is properly set to blue:
[image]

[image]

However if the color is set to one from asset catalog:
[image]

in runtime blue color is not set:

[image]

If I add setting the desired color in layoutSubviews of the cell:

```
class NotificationTextListViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        label.textColor = .blue
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

It works again. This workaround is not an option in my case as I want to do one shot configuration in cellForRowAtIndexPath and not to have to store the information about the color that has to be set in cell class.

My conclusion is that when using color from asset catalog in XIB the color gets evaluated somewhat after initialization of the cell (but before layoutSubviews). 
Any idea how to overcome this problem?

Comment: I asked same question... [Can't programmatically change color set in storyboard as color from xcassets catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583593/cant-programmatically-change-color-set-in-storyboard-as-color-from-xcassets-cat)