# UIButton backgroundColor doesn't change on first UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I'm currently developing an application in Swift and, when i run my application on an iPhone 6 (which runs iOS 12.4.6), occurs a strange problem.

I have a `UITableView` with many of `UITableViewCell` inside it and, these cells, contain a `UIButton` which `backgroundColor` needs to be updated by a specific condition. The problem is that, only the first cell, doesn't load correctly the color, on the contrary it's loaded only after the cell is reused by the `UITableView`.

I've had a similar problem before (on the same device) inside a `UIViewController` and I barely resolved it by shifting the code used to control the `backgroundColor` from the `viewDidLoad` method to the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method.

In my opinion it's something related with the storyboard overriding some values, I've already tried to set the condition on `awakeFromNib` inside the `UITableViewCell` but nothing changes, and I can't actually figure out what else may be causing this problem.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Are you using `UIColor(named:)` initializer or you have `.xcassets` folder in your project with custom colors?

Comment: 1/ Try put the code that changes background color in DispatchQueue.main.async
2/ Try to set button's background color to clear in xib/storyboard.

Comment: @vpoltave yes I'm currently using custom colors

Comment: @DuyNguyen I'll try right now

Comment: This is known issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59145038/6057764. No need to  Dispatching to main async, that's just hide the problem. Just remove named color assigning from Storyboard and assign it in code

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I've actually tried to put the code inside the DispatchQueue.main.async as suggested and it worked fine without any problems.